# Umbraco traversal to level MemberTypePropertyTypes and get the property values

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have a Member object where I am getting properties like:

```
 IMember member = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetById(id);
```

[image]

I am trying to get the postcode,agerange and its value from MemberTypePropertyTypes.
any suggestion on how to traverse till MemberTypePropertyTypes and store all the value in jobject or in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't member.GetPropertyValue("postcode") or member.Properties["postcode"].Value work?

Take a look at some practical examples of how to use MembershipHelper here: http://24days.in/umbraco/2014/dealing-with-members/

**EDIT**: Here's an example to get all Properties into a Dictionary:

```
var member = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetById(1231);
var dict = member.Properties.ToDictionary(x => x.Alias, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Yes ,it should work .but I am looking for the structure like property name and property value in a jobject for all 30+ properties.

Comment: Not sure I follow, sorry. I don't think there's a way to get all properties straight into a JObject. Updated answer with example of getting all properties into a Dictionary.